# can't start oracle service in linux

Tags: oracle

I am facing a problem during start up the service of oracle

```
Database Buffers         1677721600 bytes
Redo Buffers               33124352 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: '/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/redo03.log'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

List of /home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL

```
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 21474844672 Aug 29 12:32 temp01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall    52429312 Aug 29 14:05 redo01.log
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall    52429312 Aug 29 14:05 redo02.log
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 32212262912 Aug 29 14:41 users01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 21474844672 Aug 29 14:41 undotbs01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  1440751616 Aug 29 14:41 system01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  1807753216 Aug 29 14:41 sysaux01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  2147491840 Aug 29 14:41 POWERCENTER01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall   268443648 Aug 29 14:41 META_INDEX01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall   536879104 Aug 29 14:41 META_DATA01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  1610620928 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_QOTA02.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall   536879104 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_QOTA01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  2147491840 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_BILL_ITEM_INDEX01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 32212262912 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_BILL_ITEM01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall   536879104 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_BILL_INDEX01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  2147491840 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_BILL01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall  1073750016 Aug 29 14:41 CSA_QOTA03.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall     9977856 Aug 29 14:44 control01.ctl
```

Please assist

Comment: `/home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/redo03.log` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes... /home/oracle/oracle/oradata/ORCL/redo03.log doesn't exist. How to recover this file

Comment: That's not a programming question. Use a file recovery tool or restore your backup.

Comment: Yes.. I know that it's not a programming question.. But I didn't get any solution

Comment: Hope that answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this recovery mechanism, but it's not guaranteed.

**Back up your database (even in its broken state) BEFORE you try any recovery suggestions. You can torpedo all of your data if you fail to do this.**

You should **always** keep a regular backup of your production database -- ours runs every 12 hours.

```
STARTUP MOUNT
ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE TO TRACE;
STARTUP NOMOUNT
RECOVER DATABASE USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE UNTIL CANCEL;
enter CANCEL;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

This *may* get your database back into a corrupt state, just allow it to process then fix any inconsistent data manually (will only be transactions that were running when it failed).

Hope it helps.